# PHP OOP nested methods?

Tags: php, function, nested

I know that you can use nested functions in PHP.

Here is the question:

I have this code:

```
    class ClassName
    {
        private $data;

        function __construct()
        {

        }

        public function myFunction()
        {
            if($condition1 != NULL)
            {
                if(!empty($condition2) && $this->data->condition3 == NULL)
                {

                    $this->do1($condition2);
                    $this->do3($condition2);
                    $this->do3($condition2);
                    $this->doBLAH();

                }
                elseif(empty($checkoutItem->rebillCheckoutItemId))
                {
                    $this->do1($condition2);
                    $this->do3($condition2);
                    $this->do3($condition2);
                    $this->doSomethingElse();

                }
            }               

        }

    }
```

As you can see, this part is redundant:

```
$this->do1($condition2);
$this->do3($condition2);
$this->do3($condition2);
```

So get rid off redundancy i could create a new method:

```
    private function doSomething($condition2)
    {
        $this->do1($condition2);
        $this->do3($condition2);
        $this->do3($condition2);        
    }
```

But i don't want to. It might really mess my code up.

Just wondering if its possible to do something like:

```
        public function myFunction()
        {
            if($condition1 != NULL)
            {
                if(!empty($condition2) && $this->data->condition3 == NULL)
                {

                    $this->doSomething($condition2);
                    $this->doBLAH();

                }
                elseif(empty($checkoutItem->rebillCheckoutItemId))
                {
                    $this->doSomething($condition2);
                    $this->doSomethingElse();

                }
            }
            function doSomething($condition2)
            {
                $this->do1($condition2);
                $this->do3($condition2);
                $this->do3($condition2);        
            }               

        }
```

I tried it but it throws a `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function doSomething()`. Are there  any tricks? Am i doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

I'm working in YII framework and it gives me an exception: `BlahWidget and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "doSomething"`

Comment: do is a predefined keyword. You cannot use it for a method name. And you do not need a nested function to do that. You can make 'doSomething' a method of the class you are already working in

Comment: That's a code snippet/sample. not real code.

Comment: _But i don't want to. It might really mess my code up._ - can you explain how it would mess your code up? In fact, I think it's a good idea: some experts recommend that you regularly refactor into smaller functions that "do one thing well", are named well, and are deliberately short.

Comment: @rinchik that might be the case. My comment still stands! Use normal names for methods. This error is never going to be thrown 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function do()'

Comment: @tlenss i replaced `nameOfMyFunction()` with `do()` for demonstrating purposes. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an anonymous function in your local scope instead. Otherwise, the function will still be defined in the global scope or namespace.

This should work from PHP 5.4 because $this is used within the closure. In 5.3, you will need to do additional gymnastics. See below.

```
    public function myFunction()
    {
        $do = function ($condition2) {
            $this->do1($condition2);
            $this->do3($condition2);
            $this->do3($condition2);        
        };

        if($condition1 != NULL)
        {
            if(!empty($condition2) && $this->data->condition3 == NULL)
            {

                $do($condition2);
                $this->doBLAH();

            }
            elseif(empty($checkoutItem->rebillCheckoutItemId))
            {
                $do($condition2);
                $this->doSomethingElse();

            }
        }               

    }
```

And now the 5.3 version. Note that the functions called need to be public.

```
    public function myFunction()
    {
        $that = $this;
        $do = function ($condition2) use ($that) {
            $that->do1($condition2);
            $that->do3($condition2);
            $that->do3($condition2);        
        };

        if($condition1 != NULL)
        {
            if(!empty($condition2) && $this->data->condition3 == NULL)
            {

                $do($condition2);
                $this->doBLAH();

            }
            elseif(empty($checkoutItem->rebillCheckoutItemId))
            {
                $do($condition2);
                $this->doSomethingElse();

            }
        }               

    }
```

In an example like this, for 5.3, I would rather create a private method on the class.

Comment: I have 5.3 :( Any idea how to do it in 5.3?

Comment: The part that won't work in 5.3 is using $this inside of the anonymous function to refer to the class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have a function called `do()`. It is [reserved](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

So let's change your `do()` to `do_somthing()`. Then you need to call it with `$this->do_something()` wherever you want to make use of it.

Comment: I'm working with YII framework, it gives me an exception: `Widget and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "do"`